# Deploying Oracle PL/SQL code to QA

Tags: database, oracle

I am developing a complex Oracle application (hundreds of scripts). Until now, whenever a build was created, QA would have to drop the existing schemas, and re-apply the scripts using an installer. In most cases, each new build contains a relatively small change, but QA has to lose all of the data in order to test the new build.
Is there a way to incrementally apply the changes to their existing environments?

I've read about the mambo approach for SQL Server, but it uses TSQL and thus irrelevant to Oracle.

Comment: The question is : why do you drop all schemas/tables? Why not detect if objects exists and proceed with ALTER instructions if it is the case?

Comment: @ThomasG, this is simply the way the scripts are built. Perhaps this is actually the solution.